# Extended field for $u^2+1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I'm reading about extended field.

And I wonder what actually is field $F$ : $F_{q^2}= F (u)$, with $u^2 + 1=0$ means?

Comment: You are starting with the field $F$, and then you are “adding” a root of the polynomial $x^2+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the complex numbers built from the reals by adding $i$. Then the field is the set of sums $a+bi$ with the familiar rules. The rule for multiplication relies on the fact that $i$ is a root of the irreducible polynomial $x^2 + 1$.

The same construction works over any  finite field in which $-1$ does not have a square root. For example, the $9$ element field is (formally) the set of sums $a+bi$ with $a$ and $b$ in $F_3$ (arithmetic mod $3$) and $i^2 = -1 \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting with the field $F_q$.  Then $F_q(u)\cong \frac {F_q[X]}{(x^2+1)}\cong F_{q^2}$. Thus $u$ is being adjoined, where $u^2+1=0$.

Another way of describing it is as the two-dimensional vector space over $F_q$, with basis $\{1,u\}$.

If you start with $\Bbb R$, on the other hand,  you get $\Bbb R(i)\cong\frac{\Bbb R[X]}{(x^2+1)}\cong \Bbb C$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the field $F_p$ and the polynomial $X^2+1$.

If $X^2+1=0$ has roots in $F_p$ (for example, when $p=5$, the polynomial has $u=2,u=3$ as roots), nothing happens when you "add” u.

If $X^2+1=0$ doesn't have roots in $F_p$, then $X^2+1$ is irreducible in $F_p[X]$ and hence $$\frac{F_p[X]}{<X^2+1>}$$ is a field with $p^2$ elements. Note that $u = X+<X^2+1>$ becomes a root of this polynomial in this extension, and $\{1,u\}$ becomes  a basis of the extension over $F_p$.

Comment: Thanks May I ask that if I take f(x)=x^3+x+1 and p=4 then what is fp(x)/<x^2+1>?

Comment: @jswang Do you mean $$F_4[X]/<X^3+X+1>$$?

Comment: F4[X]/<X^2+1> ,  like Fp[X]/<X^2+1> you wrote above

Comment: @jswang I am confused... What does $f(x)=x^3+x+1$ then have to do with this? You posted a polynomial in your comment and asked some question not related to your polynomial.

Comment: @jswang Anyhow, $F_4$ has characteristic $2$. Therefore, in $F_4[X]$ you have $$x^2+1=X^2+2X+1=(X+1)^2$$ Now, adding the root $x=-1$ to $F_4$ does nothing.... On another hand, the RING $F_4[X]/<X^2+1>$ is a vector space over $F_4$ with basis $\{1,X\}$ and therefore a ring with $8$ elements. It is not a field, since in this ring $(X+1) \neq 0$ but $$(X+1)(X+1)=0$$

Comment: @jswang Note that for irreducible polynomials $f(x)$, adding a root $u$ of $f(x)$ to $F$ is the same as taking the factor $F[X]/ < f(x)>$. This follows from the First Isomorphism Theorem: $$F[X] \to F[u] ; P(x) \to P(u)$$ is an onto ring homomorphism with kernel $<f(x)>$. Therefore, by the first isomorphism theorem $$F[u] \simeq F[X]/<f(x)>$$

Comment: thanks a lot I got it

Comment: BUT, if $f(x)$ is not irreducible, adding a root $u$ is not the same as taking the factor $F[X]/ < f(x)>$. Indeed, if $P(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $u$, then $P(X) |f(x)$ and $\deg (P) < \deg(f)$. Now, by the above, since $P(X)$ is irreducible, you have $$F[u] \simeq F[X]/<P(x)> \not\simeq  F[X]/<f(x)>$$

Comment: @jswang See the extra comment for what happens when $f(x)$ is NOT irreducible.